# Get implemented types of generic interface

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, interface

I have an generic interface and I would like to have a list of the implemented data types.
With the following code I don't get any type returned. (t in types)

```
var type = typeof (IDataTypeConverter<>);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                     .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                     .Where(x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface);

foreach (var t in types)
{
    var instance = (IDataTypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(t); 
    PropertiesConverter.Add(t, instance);
}
```

This is an example of an implementation of the interface:

```
public class DecimalConverter : IDataTypeConverter, IDataTypeConverter<decimal>
    {
     ...
    }
```

Interface it selves:

```
public interface IDataTypeConverter
{
    object Convert(object value);
}

public interface IDataTypeConverter<TDataType>
{

}
```

What am I doing wrong here, why don't I get decimal as a type in my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You're checking to see if your classes are assignable to the *open generic type* `IDataTypeConverter<>` which they are not. They are only assignable to a *closed* generic type like `IDataTypeConverter<decimal>` (or other data types for `TDataType`)

```
var type = typeof (IDataTypeConverter<>);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => !x.IsInterface) //ignore interface definitions
    .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces() //for each interface implemented
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType) //if they're a generic interface
        .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type)); //check its open-generic
```

I think there might be a simpler way to check, but this will do the job. It grabs all interfaces for a type, and for each one that's a generic interface, it checks if it's underlying open generic definition is `IDataTypeConverter<>`.

EDIT: Another way to demonstrate what I mean, your existing code would work *if* for `type` you assigned `typeof(IDataTypeConverter<decimal>)` instead. That works because your types would be assignable to a `IDataTypeConverter<decimal>` but they're not assignable to `IDataTypeConverter<>` because such an operation has no meaning in C#.

Comment: Any idea how I could get the type of the interface? IDataTypeConverter<decimal> = decimal instead of DecimalConverter

Comment: @Freddy: Yup, once you have the interface type, you can use [`GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) to get at the `decimal` generic argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your type variable contains generic type definition, IDataTypeConverter is not its descendant. So IDataTypeConverter is not assignable from IDataTypeConverter<>.

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(IDataTypeConverter<>).IsGenericTypeDefinition);
Console.WriteLine(typeof(IDataTypeConverter<decimal>).IsGenericTypeDefinition);
```

To check that some generic type is of the same generic type definition you can use predicate:

```
x => .GetInterfaces()
     .Any(item => item.IsGenericType && item.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type)
```